# PyQt5 ComboBox can't figure out

Tags: python, combobox, pyqt5, qcombobox

Good day!

I have started to learn Python last week, I am surprised how easy and understandable it is compared to other languages, but I can't figure out one thing.

I have scraped a table (NBA Team stats from last 5 games) from a website, it updates every day.
There are 30 rows in that table (30 NBA Teams) and 19 Columns (Stats like Points, Rebounds, Blocks, etc).

I want to put 30 Team Names in ComboBox Widget and when A Team is chosen, I want it to show data of that specific team (These 19 columns). The Data shown would be in QTableWidget.

```
class Window(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.initUI()

def initUI(self):

    comboStatsText = QLabel('Home Team', self)
    comboStatsText.move(15, 10)
    comboStatsBox = QComboBox(self)
    comboStatsBox.move(15, 30)


    #Combo Box Data
    comboStatsBox.addItem(name)
    comboStatsBox.addItem(name1)
```

I have successfully went to stage where I choose A team and a tablewidget pops and shows data, but If I choose another team again, it doesn't change. I have looked up how to change it when activated, but I could not do it.

I have looked up something with indexes of combobox, could not understand how to implement it. Would it be like this?

if index(of combobox) = 1(corresponding team) then
         show data of that team?

I hope you get the idea :/ I am really bad at explaining things and English is not my native language. Any help or suggestions would be much appreciated, THANKS!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write a function that receives a signal from the combobox for your selection event. Perhaps the `activated` signal. Then you need to clear the existing tablewidget and write in your new data.

Something like this:

```
combostatsbox.activated.connect(self.load_team)

def load_team():
    self.team_table_widget.clear()
    # Set your values now
```

Comment: Thanks, I have got the Idea. What if the data is different on every team chosen? If every team had index from 0 to 29 that would be easier, if in combo box team is chosen with index 0 then I would create a table with specific data like in your example.

Comment: Thats why you use the `clear` method. That will erase the data loaded for the previous team and allow you to load and populate the data for the newly selected team.

Comment: So my ComboBox consists of 30 Team Names, If I pick Team #3 I need to create a table with data of team 3. How should I know which Team was picked so I can create a table with data I scraped for that team? Ahh man, you probably think I am stupid. :D

Comment: You can use the `.currentText()` method to get the team name from the combobox. And everybody has to start out somewhere. Best advice anyone will give you is to always read the source and documentation for everything.